# Display data based on user input

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page with 2 columns (Side and Middle)

on the side column, I have a form with a date and a button (View Summary Report).

When the user selects the **date** and clicks the **button**, it must **fetch the data from the MySQL DB** and display the results in the middle column.

When I do a call action to the get_summary_sheet, it displays the info on a new page. This confirms that it is working fine. BUT, I don't want to display it on a new page. I want to display it in the middle column once the user clicks the button.

I was doing research and exploring options to use the onclick function.

**Here is my side column:**

```
<div class="column side">
    Select Date:
      <br>
      <input type="date" id="select_summarydate" name="select_summarydate" required><br>
      
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Display Report</button>
    
</div>
```

**Below is a sample of the code in the PHP file:**

```
     $yourDate = $_GET['select_summarydate'];
     
     $sqlpole="select count(*) as totalpole from user where MeterType = 'Pole Mounted' AND Category = 'Inspection' AND Date = '".$yourDate."%'";
     $resultpole=mysqli_query($con,$sqlpole);
     $datapole=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultpole);
```

**I need to call the results to the middle column and display it in the table:**

```
<div class="column middle">
    * display results of function in php file        
</div>
```

**Below is a snippet of the JS code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        // function below will run get_summary_sheet and should display in middle column
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "get_summary_sheet.php" ,
            ???????,
            ???????
     });
</script>
```

***What code must go into the Javascript function?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
   var select_summarydate = $('#select_summarydate').val()
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_summary_sheet.php" ,
        data: {
            select_summarydate : select_summarydate
          },
        success: function(resp){
             $('.middle').html(resp)    
       } 
   });
 }
```

this is a complete ajax function with sending data and displaying the fetched data in html

your php code will look like below

```
$yourDate = $_GET['select_summarydate'];
 
 $sqlpole="select count(*) as totalpole from user where MeterType = 'Pole Mounted' AND Category = 'Inspection' AND Date = '".$yourDate."%'";
 $resultpole=mysqli_query($con,$sqlpole);
 while ($single = $resultpole->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  $single['firstcolumn'].' '.$single['secondcolumn'] 
       .'<br>';
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I copied the code but its still not working.

When I check on the developer console in Chrome, i see this error:

        Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
            at myFunction ((index):216)
            at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):152)

Comment: try the updated code,  remove `preventdefault`, coz don't have `submit` at your button call.

Comment: Thank you very much! that did the trick! You are a legend CodeBug!

Comment: please check out this question and let me know if you are able to help. Please!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432056/how-do-idisplay-25-rows-and-search-entire-table

Comment: happy to help @Slamho, happy coding

Comment: Please check out this question and let me know if you are able to help. PLEASE!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65434868/create-function-to-search-entire-table-and-not-one-column-only